Why does ''X{1H} nucleus'' NMR experiment doesn't give any signal while 2D [1H-X] HSQC & HMQC experiment do give signals?
During my lab work, I sometimes have to look for the existence of some specific X-nucleus containing components and for this, I perform X{1H} NMR screening experiments (e.g. 31P{1H} or 15N{1H}...). However, I noticed that ''sometimes'' I don't get any X nucleus signal while when I use 2D [1H-X] HSQC or HMBC experiments on the same sample I do get signals. Has anyone of you encountered this issue before? could it be hardware a related problem, knowing that all the performance control tests on the spectrometer, gave good results? For you potential answers, please take into account the fact that :

The SW window is always set wide enough to look for any potential signal.
The analyzed samples are highly concentrated (more than 40.000 ppm), so the present problem is not related to sensitivity issues

Thank you.
